# How to change font-size in Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

My website works great in every browser except for Firefox. For some reason the browser increases the size of the text larger than any other browser and it pushes the text out of its div. How can I make the text smaller for only Firefox?

I have tried this code but it did not work,

```
 <script>
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {

        $('.first_develop_div').css({
         'font-size': '12px'
        });
        $('.second_develop_div').css({
         'font-size': '12px'
        });

    }//end if firefox

  </script>
```

Comment: Does it only happen on your Firefox or everyone's?

Comment: Have you tries with: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ >> http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/javascript

Comment: Maybe the `.css({ ... })` part is the one that is not working, it maybe overriden by other inherited style or class

Comment: Do you have Firefox set to zoom the font in? If you hold down control, and scroll the mouse wheel up and down to change the font size, does that help?

Comment: @Charlie74 why not simply [CTRL]+[0] to reset default.

Comment: What jQuery version you use? `$.browser.mozilla` does not work in 2.x.x

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan wasn't aware of the keyboard shortcut, thanks. Will have to remember that one.

Comment: I am using `  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Also I am on a Mac so how can I change the font on a mac?

Comment: @user2861085 have you tried with [CMD] *(really?)* + [0]

Comment: Most browsers allow users to change the size of text and the font used to whatever they like regardless of what is specified in the page. You can't control that with script.

Answer (score 0):

use this it may help...

```
if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) {      
  $('.first_develop_div').css({
     'font-size': '12px'
    });
    $('.second_develop_div').css({
     'font-size': '12px'
    });
return "Firefox";
} 
else {
return "unknown";
 }
```